# WinForms : Form loses visual style when opened as Modal

Tags: winforms, components, dotnetbar

I am using `DevComponents` components to create forms and as you know these components come with a `StyleManager` that user can change the visual style of a form. the problem is when i try to open these forms as `Modal`, they lose their visual style and switch back to original windows style.

this is the code from `Form1.Designer` (as i mentioned i am using `OfficeForm`) :

```
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits DevComponents.DotNetBar.OfficeForm
.
.
.
```

this is the code which i use that opens form as `MDIChild` which works just fine :

```
Public Sub OpenMDI(ByVal frm As Form)
    frm.MdiParent = MainMenu
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

this is the code i am using to open form as `Modal` :

```
Form1.ShowDialog()
```

and these are the screenshots with and without visual styles ([image: with] - [image: without])

Comment: Use the [vendor's support channels](http://www.devcomponents.com/support.aspx) to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `EnableGlass` property of from to `False`

eg. :

```
Form1.EnableGlass = False;
```